# Проверка для скидок (discount) в корзине - OpenCart

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

У меня есть товар с опциями. Я его использую, как форму заказа. Например, я совершаю заказ с параметрами:
A - 333
B - 222
C - 111
Нажимаю добавить в корзину, и в корзине отображается мой заказ с этими параметрами.
Потом я делаю еще один, точно такой же заказ, он попадает в корзину, а в корзине увеличивается только его кол-во, т.к. параметры идентичные. Если я делаю еще один заказ с параметрами:
A - 444
B...
C... 
Товар добавляется в корзину, но уже в новую таблицу. Я не могу понять, как делается проверка на опции.

Дело в том, что у меня установлена скидка на заказ товара от 2-х штук. - 6% , от 3 шт. - 8%, от 4 шт. - 10%  и т.д. Но, нужно, чтобы скидка распространялась только на заказ с определенными параметрами, т.е. в приведенном выше примере у меня в корзине находится 3 товара (2 товара с идентичными параметрами и 1 с другими параметрами) в итоге скидка начисляется, как за 3 товара, а должно быть за 2 товара, а 3-й должен считаться по полной сумме, потому что заказан в единичном кол-ве.

Я не понимаю до конца, как это можно сделать, но предположил, что можно как-то сделать проверку на идентичность параметров, если товаров с одинаковыми параметрами меньше 2-х шт, то скидку не подключать...

Мне подсказали, что нужно "пилить скидку - помимо количества товаров учитывать еще и опции"... Но мне бы немного больше информации, пока еще сложно дается самостоятельно решать такие задачи.

В system\library\cart.php
где-то в районе 180 строки есть запрос

```
$product_discount_query = $this->db->query("SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id .    "'AND quantity <= '" . (int)$discount_quantity . "' AND ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW()) AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY quantity DESC, priority ASC, price ASC LIMIT 1");
```

а ниже условие

```
if ($product_discount_query->num_rows) {
  $price = $product_discount_query->row['price'];
}
```

Кажется, если по sql запросу все устраивает, то он присваивает скидку.

значит, с помощью подсказки, я решил, что можно в sql запрос, добавить еще и проверку на опции, в итоге я сделал вот так:

```
$product_discount_query = $this->db->query("SELECT price FROM "
. DB_PREFIX . "product_discount LEFT JOIN " 
. DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov LEFT JOIN "
. DB_PREFIX . "option_value ov ON (pov.option_value_id = ov.option_value_id)   WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'
 AND pov.product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$option_value . "'
 AND pov.product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "'
 AND quantity <= '" . (int)$discount_quantity . "'
 AND ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW())
 AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY quantity DESC,  priority ASC, price ASC LIMIT 1");
```

... но, получаю ошибку:

> Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE product_id = '2419' AND pov.product_option_value_id = '27' AND p' at line 1
>   Error No: 1064

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно нужно написать запрос?

Comment: а для LEFT JOIN можно пропускать ON? у вас между product_discount и  product_option_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя задача решилась не SQL запросом, нужно было заменить этот кусок кода

```
// Product Discounts
$discount_quantity = 0;

foreach ($this->session->data['cart'] as $key_2 => $quantity_2) {
    $product_2 = explode(':', $key_2);
    if ($product_2[0] == $product_id) {
        $discount_quantity += $quantity_2;
    }
}
```

на

```
$discount_quantity = $quantity;
```